# Including stdlib.h causes code to be unable to be compiled properly

Tags: c

I have a piece of code when I need to include stdlib.h. When I do not include this header, I have no problems compiling my code, but the moment I include the header, my code refuses to compile. It tells me that it expected an identifier or "(" before numerical constant. I have looked through my code and cannot find any issue, and as stated, the code compiles perfectly without including that header.

I am new to C, so excuse my poor code, I am simply wanting to figure out why it would be giving me this error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int execute(char **args)
{

}


char** parse(void)
{
  char command[256];
  fgets(command, sizeof(command), stdin);

  char delimiter[] = " "; 
  char * pointer = strtok(command, delimiter);

  int tokens = 0;
  char ** final_command;

  while (pointer != NULL)
  {
   // final_command = (char**)realloc(final_command,   
      // (tokens+1)*sizeof(char*));
    //printf("%s\n", pointer);

   //pointer = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
  }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int EXIT_SUCCESS = 1;
  do 
  {
    printf("MyShell> ");
    char ** command = parse();
  } while (EXIT_SUCCESS);  

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I compile using the command gcc -o MyShell MyShell.c
The exact error I am getting says "error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant int EXIT_SUCCESS = 1;"

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status

Comment: You cannot redeclare a `#define`d numeric constant macro as an identifier, because by the time identifiers are considered, the macro will already be replaced by the numeric constant, and identifiers cannot start with a digit.

Comment: It honestly seems like you could use a good beginners book or two, and start over from the beginning.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but a common convention for programs is to return 0 on success or non-zero on error. So assigning 1 to `EXIT_SUCCESS`, if it was possible, would confuse anyone reading your code. It would be just as fun as swapping the meaning of the `+` and `-` operators.

Answer (score 2):

EXIT_SUCCESS is a standard macro (definition) in C. Do not use it as a variable name.

Comment: thank you so much. I am new to c, and that variable came from starting code a professor gave us.

Answer (score 0):

Like `NULL`, [`EXIT_SUCCESS`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22p3) is a **macro** defined in `<stdlib.h>`, if you include `<stdlib.h>` you must not use this identifier for other purposes.

In any case your code does not make much sense because it looks like you've got an infinite loop there in `main`.

Comment: Like I said, this I was simply asking for help with why my code was not compiling. I was unable to go any further in my assignment, hence why I still have places to work on.